# Get the Users list : Except the user which is looking for the Users / Logged In User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Get all the users except current logged in user, so for example if a user X is logged in and he wanted to see all the users, the query should return all the users except the user X.

I just getting started with python so it's the learning phase, I am very thankful for your help. So far i have tried with different params:

```
users = User.objects.filter(username!=current_user.username)
```

Comment: `exclude` instead of `filter` will do what you want. And refer to [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) to learn more about Django queries.

Comment: user = User.objects.exclude(username=current_user.username)

Comment: @dirkgroten hey i just wanted to ask something can we post data from one app template to the view on another app is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem too. That's I tried to add model before variable belong to  [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-one-to-many-database-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy)

```
users = User.objects.filter(User.username!=current_user.username)
```